# Metadata about a column in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm trying to figure out a way to store metadata about a column without repeating myself.

I'm currently working on a generic dimension loading SSIS package that will handle all my dimensions. It currently does :

1. Create a temporary table identical to the given table name in parameters (this is a generic stored procedure that receive the table name as parameter, and then do : `select top 0 * into ##[INSERT ORIGINAL TABLE NAME HERE] from [INSERT ORIGINAL TABLE NAME HERE]`).
2. ==> Here we insert custom code for this particular dimension that will first query the data from a datasource and get my delta, then transform the data and finally loads it into my temporary table.
3. Merge the temporary table into my original table with a T-SQL MERGE, taking care of type1 and type2 fields accordingly.

My problem right now is that I have to maintain a table with all the fields in it to store a metadata to tell my scripts if this particular field is type1 or type2... this is nonsense, I can get the same data (minus type1/type2) from sys.columns/sys.types.

I was ultimately thinking about renaming my fields to include their type in it, such as :
FirstName_T2, LastName_T2, Sex_T1 (well, I know this can be type2, let's not fall into that debate here).

What do you guyz would do with that? My solution (using a table with that metadata) is currently in place and working, but it's obvious that repeating myself from the systables to a custom table is nonsense, just for a simple type1/type2 info.

UPDATE: I also thought about creating user defined types like varchar => t1_varchar, t2_varchar, etc. This sounds like something a bit sluggy too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is bad, but I will post an answer to my own question... Thanks to GBN for the help tho!

I am now storing "flags" in the "description" field of my columns. I, for example, can store a flag this way : "TYPE_2_DATA".

Then, I use this query to get the flag back for each and every column :

```
select columns.name as [column_name]
      ,types.name as [type_name]
      ,extended_properties.value as [column_flags]
  from sys.columns 
 inner join sys.types
         on columns.system_type_id = types.system_type_id
  left join sys.extended_properties
         on extended_properties.major_id = columns.object_id 
        and extended_properties.minor_id = columns.column_id  
        and extended_properties.name = 'MS_Description'
 where object_id = ( select id from sys.sysobjects where name = 'DimDivision' )
   and is_identity = 0
 order by column_id
```

Now I can store metadata about columns without having to create a separate table. I use what's already in place and I don't repeat myself. I'm not sure this is the best possible solution yet, but it works and is far better than duplicating information.

In the future, I will be able to use this field to store more metadata, where as : "TYPE_2_DATA|ANOTHER_FLAG|ETC|OH BOY!".

UPDATE :

I now store the information in separate extended properties. You can manage extended properties using `sp_addextendedproperty` and `sp_updateextendedproperty` stored procedures. I have created a simple store procedure that help me to update those values regardless if they currently exist or not :

```
create procedure [dbo].[UpdateSCDType]
    @tablename nvarchar(50),
    @fieldname nvarchar(50),
    @scdtype  char(1),
    @dbschema nvarchar(25) = 'dbo'
as
begin

    declare @already_exists int;

    if ( @scdtype = '1' or @scdtype = '2' )
    begin

         select @already_exists = count(1)
          from sys.columns 
         inner join sys.extended_properties 
                 on extended_properties.major_id = columns.object_id 
                and extended_properties.minor_id = columns.column_id 
                and extended_properties.name     = 'ScdType' 
         where object_id = (select sysobjects.id from sys.sysobjects where sysobjects.name = @tablename) 
           and columns.name = @fieldname

        if ( @already_exists = 0 )
        begin

            exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
                 @name       = N'Scd_Type', 
                 @value      = @scdtype, 
                 @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
                 @level0name = @dbschema,
                 @level1type = N'TABLE',
                 @level1name = @tablename,
                 @level2type = N'COLUMN',
                 @level2name = @fieldname

        end
        else
        begin

            exec sys.sp_updateextendedproperty 
                 @name       = N'Scd_Type', 
                 @value      = @scdtype, 
                 @level0type = N'SCHEMA',
                 @level0name = @dbschema,
                 @level1type = N'TABLE',
                 @level1name = @tablename,
                 @level2type = N'COLUMN',
                 @level2name = @fieldname

        end

    end

end
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Everything you need should already be in [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx)

I can't follow your thinking of *not* using provided tables/views...

Edit: As scarpacci mentioned, this somewhat portable if needed.

Comment: is absolutely right. You should be using the information_schema views which are ANSI Standard and can be found in other DB platforms (SQL Server, Oracle, MySql, etc). Very useful.

Comment: I agree with you. But the information about my columns being handled as type1 or type2 data in my ETLs can't be stored there. Or can it be?

Comment: Create a view on top of the information with that info and then leverage that view.

Comment: Yeah so that means I have to create a custom table to store that information. I cannot add some metadata to my columns without having a custom table.

Comment: What is "type1" or "type2" exactly?

Comment: Oh Sorry! type1 and type2 refer to the kind of history you keep in a datawarehouse. Type1 means you simply overwrite existing data, while type2 means that you have to expire the current record (so a start and end dates) and create a new record with the new data in it.

Comment: In which case, I would prefix tables with T1 or T2 because it's easier than having another table. And I can't think of anything cleverer

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought (but in my case some fields can trigger type1, some other type2, so it would be prefixed on the fields). BUT, the downside of that, is that if we ever switch a field from type2 to type1, we have to alter the database schema... which is bad for that kind of modification.

Comment: Oh I just figured out a way to achieve what I want. I can store some free text in a column "description", and then get it back in the sys.extended_properties table. I can store something like "TYPE_1_DATA" or "TYPE_2_DATA" flags in that description. That's not perfect, but quite better that having a separate table.

Comment: I should have thought of that. We use extended properties heavily to document and explain, but not for programmatic or metadata use. Good thinking

Comment: Thank you very much for the help about my issue, I upvoted your answer but finally ended up posting what I do as the answer. Thanks!